# error resolving "nmcheck.genome.org": temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: networking, wireless, display-resolution

I'm new to Ubuntu (20.04), and I've been dealing with a connection issue on public Wi-Fi for a few months now. When I connect to the network and wait for the login screen to pop up, I keep getting an error. Strangely, my phone works just fine on the same network. I'm not sure how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it really say nmcheck.genome.org or is it nmcheck.**gnome**.org? iirc the latter is used to determine whether you are behind a captive portal (which might be the case for a public wifi connection). See for example **4.15 Checking connectivity** under [NetworkManager Configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager#Configuration)